# What is the relationship between Windows BitLocker and Hasleo BitLocker Anywhere?

Tags: disk-encryption, bitlocker

Whilst researching alternatives to BitLocker which work on Windows 10 Home, I came across a product called "[BitLocker Anywhere](https://www.easyuefi.com/bitlocker-anywhere/bitlocker-anywhere-home.html)" from Hasleo. Since they use such similar names I was trying to figure out if they are related.

Is this a completely separate and competing product (and if so, how did they get away with such an obvious trademark infringement?) or is it actually the same software somehow repackaged?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like other have had your same question and discussed it on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/8rhis8/bitlocker_anywhere/)

The summary was that it's likely a hack to get BitLocker working in Windows 10 Home, which doesn't normally allow for BitLocker, but that it's not really trustable because they are infringing on the trademark (unless they pay MS some royalties to use the name).

Comment: Thanks - I didn't see that one. interesting to find out it's relatively new on the market so I guess it's probably not legit but MS just haven't shut it down yet

Comment: It's 2023 and the product is still up and running. Latest version released Oct 2022.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Halseo BitLocker Anywhere is basically just the Control Panel Applet (CPL).  You can actually control BitLocker using the cmd prompt in admin mode.  So it wouldn't be too difficult to write an app to just issue those commands.

Comment: So, this is speculation that it is a CPL? From a quick look at the product page, it appears to be more than a CPL.